# How to tell if a client is attempting to connect to server in c++ winsock

Tags: c++, winsock2

I want a server to accept a client with this code

```
SOCKADDR_IN cliaddr = { 0 };
int len = sizeof(cliaddr);
_sockClient = accept(_sockServer, (SOCKADDR*)&cliaddr, &len);
```

Both _sockClient and _sockServer are SOCKETs, _sockServer's SOCKET already connected to the server.

Before I accept, I want to check `_sockServer` if there is an incoming client request to join. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this, though I don't know how. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

By default, a socket operates in blocking mode.  So, you could simply call `accept()` and let it block the calling thread until a new connection is accepted.  That is the easiest approach.  If you don't want to block the calling thread, you could call `accept()` in another thread instead.

But, provided you don't want to block any thread at all, then yes, there are other ways to handle this, depending on your programming model:

- Poll the socket using the `readfds` parameter of [`select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select). The socket will be in a *readable* state if it has any pending connections waiting to be accepted.
- Use [`WSAEventSelect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaeventselect) to signal a waitable `WSAEVENT` object whenever an `FD_ACCEPT` event occurs, indicating that pending connections are available to accept. You can then poll/wait on that object using [`WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsawaitformultipleevents), and use [`WSAEnumNetworkEvents()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaenumnetworkevents) to reset the object's state for the next wait.
- Use [`WSAAsyncSelect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsaasyncselect) to receive a window message whenever an `FD_ACCEPT` event occurs.
- Use [`AcceptEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-acceptex) instead of `accept()` to start an asynchronous acceptance in the background. It will report its completion to you via Overlapped I/O or an I/O Completion Port.

See [Overlapped I/O and Event Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/overlapped-i-o-and-event-objects-2) in Winsock's documentation for more details.